# Jackson ObjectMapper: How to omit (ignore) null array element [null]

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have Json array containing `null` value in array.

```
{
  myArray: [ null ]
}
```

How to configure Jackson ObjectMapper to ignore such `null` array elements - as if it was empty array `[]`?

Constrains:

- No control of source class - it is a third party class
- Array element type is unknown upfront
- Array(s) name is unknown upfront

Comment: I don’t believe Jackson has this out of the box. You’ll need a custom deserializer. Or strip it yourself from the pojo.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Do you know a way how to plugin some post-processor to ObjectMapper?

Comment: No, I think it’ll be quite involved process. Find the standard list/set/collection and array deserializers, wrap them in the processor(s), then reregister them to deserialize those types. Might be easier to change your server ‍♂️

Answer (score 2):

You can use `contentNulls` property from [JsonSetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonSetter.html#contentNulls()) annotation. Your `POJO` class could look like below:

```
class ArrayWrapper {
    private List<String> myArray;

    @JsonSetter(contentNulls = Nulls.SKIP)
    public void setMyArray(List<String> myArray) {
        this.myArray = myArray;
    }

    public List<String> getMyArray() {
        return myArray;
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How to exclude null list items with Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57096639/how-to-exclude-null-list-items-with-jackson/57102742#57102742)

Comment: It seems to go in correct direction, but I cannot modify POJOs (or very hardly). I am looking for a solution with configuration ObjectMapper itself only.

Comment: @MichalFoksa, use `MixIn` feature. Examples: [Dynamic addition of fasterxml Annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25306786/51591), [Jackson conditional @JsonUnwrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25435990/51591)

Comment: :( Mixin is not generic  - it does not apply for every array / list.

Comment: @MichalFoksa, could you edit your question and add more details? Could you create an example where `MixIn` does not apply to array/list?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe @JsonIclude works?

```
   @JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_EMPTY, content=Include.NON_NULL)
```

http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html?is-external=true

Comment: I believe this applies to the field, not to the contents of the JSON array. Have you tried it?